# Regex: Select everything before particular character and other substring, or select everything if neither substring nor character exist

Tags: regex, string, character

I need a single regex expression that can select everything before a `:` character, and/or everything before the substring `Hello`. If neither `:` or `Hello` are in the string, I need to select everything.

Examples and Expected Output:

- `"Let's go see Hello Dolly: A Classic Movie"` --> `"Let's go see "`

  - Note that a string can have both substring `"Hello"` and character `":"` character, and it should select everything before whichever occurs first.
- `"Let's go see: A Classic Movie, Hello Dolly"` --> `"Let's go see"`

  - Note that a string can have both substring `"Hello"` and character `":"` character, and it should select everything before whichever occurs first.
- `"Howdy"` --> `"Howdy"`

  - Selects entire string if no `"Hello"` or `":"` found.
- `"Well Hi, Hello My Friend"` --> `"Well Hi, "`

  - Selects everything before `"Hello"`.
- `"My Favorite Pizza Place: NYC"` --> `"My Favorite Pizza Place"`

  - Selects everything before `":"`.
- `"Hello"` --> `""`

  - Selects everything before `"Hello"`, in this case returning an empty string.

So far, I've found this expression, `(^[^:]+)`, which will return everything before a `":"` character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should do what you want. It looks for a minimal number of characters to capture (`.*?`) followed by either `:`, `Hello` or the end of line (`$`):

```
^(.*?)(?=:|Hello|$)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cUrSTK/1)

This will work if you are testing one value at a time and don't use the `g` flag. Otherwise the string `"Hello"` will match twice, once with the empty string at the beginning of the line, and once with `Hello`. If that is an issue, you can use this regex which prevents that from happening while still capturing values such as `"Howdy"`:

```
^(?:.*?)(?=Hello|:)|^(?!.*(Hello|:)).*$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cUrSTK/4)

Comment: solved & a big thanks! the first solution you listed is exactly what I want, and thank you for the additional explanation, too.

Answer (score 0):

`^(?:(.*?)(?:(?:Hello)|:).*|.*)$`

This regex should do the trick - [Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/ikC5n4/4)

```regex
Breakdown

^(?:(.*?)(?:(?:Hello)|:).*|(.*))$

^(?:                           )$    force a full string match - this triggers the wildcard if one isn't found
                          |          select either of the two, but prefer the first
                           (.*)      capture any characters (when there's no : or Hello)
    (.*?)                            capture any characters, but as few as possible - this is the match you're looking for
                        .*           clean up any extra characters
         (?:           )             non capture group
                     |               choose either...
                      :              a colon
            (?:Hello)                or "Hello:
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for `Howdy`, there is no match in group 1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this expression might be somewhat close, or maybe not:

```
^([^:\r\n]*?)(?=Hello|:)|^(?!Hello).*$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bqe27I/1/)